# Angular Hide / Show

Tags: html, angular, angular2-template

I want to show `coucou` when points are 100. The console log work well, but the `coucou` in the html doesn't work.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  points = 100;
  public show = false;
  constructor() {

  }

  coucou() {
    if (this.points == 100) {
      this.show = true;
      console.log("prout");
    }
    else {
      this.show = false;
      console.log("ozdjfezifj");
    }

  }
}
```

Html side :

```
<div *ngIf="coucou()">
  <div style="color:red;">coucou</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using a function in `*ngIf` it should return true or false.So use   `this.show` in  `*ngIf`

```
<div *ngIf="show">
  <div style="color:red;">coucou</div>
</div>
```

or if you want to use the function instead of  `this.show` then return true/false from the function

```
coucou() {
   return this.points == 100 ? true : false; 
 }
```

Or you could directly use

```
<div *ngIf="points == 100">
  <div style="color:red;">coucou</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Perfect answer ! Thank ;)

Answer (score 1):

`ngIf` expression should evaluate to a truthy/falsy value. So if a function is bound to `ngIf` it should return either `true` or `false`.

Change is required in `cocou` function

```
coucou() {
    return (this.points === 100);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because the expression evaluated in the `ngIf` attribute value has to be *truthy* and `coucou()` doesn't seem to do that as `console.log` call returns `undefined`.

Answer (score 0):

You can do and avoid all the other boilerplate

```
 <div *ngIf="points == 100">
    <div style="color:red;">coucou</div>
 </div>
```